# Why is STDERR redirected to STDOUT

Tags: c, stdout, stderr

I noticed that we have mainly 3 file streams. They are STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR..
My question is why is STDERR redirected to STDOUT?

Answer (score 34):

`stderr` is not redirected to `stdout`. Both streams are only connected to the same device (the current screen or terminal) by default.

You can redirect them to different files:

```
$ command > stdout.log 2> stderr.log
```

In order to actually redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, you have to issue:

```
$ command 2>&1
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not; it just happens that both stdout and stderr are typically mapped to the same output stream (usually the console).  If you redirect stdout to a file for example you will find that stderr remains directed to the console.

The important point is that they are independently redirectable.

Answer (score 0):

Like `stdout`, `stderr` is usually directed to the output device of the standard console (generally, the screen). That means, `stderr` is not redirected to `stdout` but they share a common file descriptor. It is possible to redirect `stderr` to some other destination from within a program using the [freopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/freopen.html) function.

Comment: Well, technically they don't even share a file descriptor: `stdout` is `fd 1` and `stderr` is `fd 2`.

Comment: Fd of stdout is 1 and fd os stderr is 2 then how can they share fd?

Comment: @user559208, they don't. Each one has its own file descriptor.